# Reading JSON Data after being sent to php file

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have JSON encoded data which I am calling in PHP and saving into the variable. I want to read the variable elements now, Here is the JSON code

```
"ticket": {
    "assignee": {
        "id": "testing1@test.com",
        "name": "John Doe"
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "author": {
                "id": "testing@test.com",
                "name": "testing",
                "type": "agent1"
            },
            "date": "2014-08-18T10:05:05Z",
            "is_private": false,
            "message": "Hey, I have a problem with...",
            "source": {
                "type": "agent-app-manual",
                "url": null
            },
            "type": "message"
        }
    ],

    "groups": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "All operators"
        }
    ],
    "id": "CCWWM",

    "requester": {
        "mail": "test@test.com",
        "name": "Mary Brown"
    },
    "status": "test1",
    "subject": "issue1"
}
```

Below is how my php file is collecting the JSON data and saving it to the variable then decoding the data, Now I am not sure how to read the values. For instance how can I get the value of name or email, Here is my php code.

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($data);
```

This is how I am trying to read the data but its not pulling up anything

```
$email = $data->visitor->email;
```

Comment: `print_r($data);` will show you.

Comment: "`$data->visitor`"  Where are you getting the `visitor` part?  That's not even anywhere in the JSON that you're showing?  In fact, `email` isn't anywhere in there either.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see `visitor` in your JSON anywhere.
Try `$data->ticket->requester->mail`

Edit: also, make sure you put `{}` around the full JSON block if you're not already

Answer (score 0):

I don't see visitor or email in the JSON you posted. Does your JSON-API require a token?

Based on what I do see, you should be able to:

```
$email = $data->ticket->requester->mail;
```

You're on the right path but I feel like some code wasn't posted for us to help better.
Also do you get anything with *print_r($data);*  or *error_log(print_r($data))* ?